# trigger to set or insert timestamp on last row BEFORE INSERT

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i need to add a trigger that will set the timestamp or insert a timestamp on the last row in the table before a new row is inserted without changing the datecreated timestamp

//my table looks like this:

`````
```` topic varchar
```` payload int
```` datecreated timestamp  current_timestamp
```` dateended timestamp no  (this needs to get up updated with the current time before a new row get's inserted in the table)
any ideeas ?
`````

Comment: A trigger isn't allowed to update the same table that it's triggering on.

Comment: is there any way i can achieve this?

Comment: Why are you changing a different row, rather than putting the current timestamp in the new row?

Comment: i'm trying to achieve something like DateEnded so i can get the time difference between inserts in the table

Comment: do you know anything about generated columns?

Comment: A generated column is in the same row, not a different row.

Comment: Join the table with itself and subtract the timestamps between adjacent rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this in a trigger, because a trigger cannot action the table it was fired upon.

A typical solution would be to create a stored procedure for that purpose, that would run the update and the insert sequentially (preferrably in the same transaction). From your application, you would invoque the stored procedure instead of running the insert query.

But I think that it would be simpler to compute the information on the fly when querying the table. If you are running MySQL 8.0, you can use window functions:

```
select
    topic, 
    payload, 
    datecreated,
    lead(datecreated) over(order by datecreated) dateended
from mytable
```

In earlier versions, you can use a correlated subquery:

```
select
    t.topic, 
    t.payload, 
    t.datecreated,
    (select min(datecreated) from mytable t1 where t1.datecreated > t.datecreated) dateended
from mytable t
```

Answer (score 0):

You should always avoid to store data redundantly. Instead of adding an additional column you should just calculate this column:

```
SELECT topic, payload, datecreated as start, (SELECT datecreated FROM my_table where datecreated > start order by datecreated LIMIT 1) as end FROM my_table
```

Comment: both of your query's return errors i'm gonna research about windows thank you both for your help